# How I Can Show/Render Data Binding from Angularjs in a Jquery Onclick?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm Working in a personal project but I have a small problem when i want to render some data binding from angularjs in jquery, this is the code.

```
<div class="claimButton claimActive">
    <a href="{{ product.url }}" target="_blank" onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})">CLAIM</a>
</div>
```

The principal problem inside here

This the original code `onclick="startTimer(0,5)"` but when i turn in databinding from angularjs `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"` stop working and no render the numbers.

I hope that somebody help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you need to show more code, and describe exactly what issue you are having

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click bind with angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097374/jquery-click-bind-with-angularjs)

Comment: ngclick is no working

Comment: use ng-click directive

Comment: when I try to use ng directive then all the onclick is null

Comment: try that onclick="angular.element(this).scope().<your function>(this)" - if i understand your question well

Comment: My problem is: This the original code `onclick="startTimer(0,5)"` but when i turn in databinding from angularjs `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"` , stop working and no render the numbers.

Comment: Excuse me for no explain good, English is me second language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have angular app and controller
you can do so

```
<div class="claimButton claimActive">
    <a href="{{ product.url }}" target="_blank" ng-click="startTimer($index,product.time)">CLAIM</a>
</div>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.startTimer = function(x,y){
    //do your code  x=$index, y=product.time
}
```

Comment: I Already made the changes, but still no working, it render when I use ng directive but is necessary the function onclick for start the timer when is clicked.

Comment: i guess i miss understood your question than! and i guess that you not staying in that page when you click the claim ? means that the controller binding again if you use the same controller

Comment: You can try the project here https://www.astrofeina.co/angularjs/ so when you click in CLAIM the counter start when the code is `onclick="startTimer(0,5)"` but when the code is `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"` the numbers no render please check and tell me if you see something

Comment: so that didnt help? onclick="angular.element(this).scope().startTimer(this)" but cant pass params

Comment: this is a ticking clock check it please

Comment: chek it https://plnkr.co/edit/m1R1PesR0HoblSaN6M1T?p=preview this, so now try to `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"` to `onclick="startTimer(0,5)"` and you gonna see how its work

Comment: the script is working good but now i need to render the numbers in binding but is no render the numbers, good idea use the plnkr

Comment: I already check, so ¿Do you think that probably I have to turn my jQuery script to AngularJS?, is not way to render the binding x,y in `onclick="startTimer(x,y)"`?

Comment: yah or you can do it with out passing params like this one i showed you with onclick -  updated plnkr check the second claim btn

Comment: ¿can you implement `onclick="angular.element(this).scope().startTimer(this)"` in my Plunker? maybe im not doing this good as well

Comment: updated my plnkr the way you want. ofcurse you need to updrade that to work the way you want but its in general

Comment: ¡Thank You for your help! now I have idea about what to do